# How can I use javascript to create a string consisting of every ISO/IEC 8859-1 character possible?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, qr-code, typed-arrays

I want to create a string consisting of every character possible and see if any of the popular QR readers are able to read each and every char from [this QR Barcode](http://dojo.telerik.com/IGoT/7).

My problem is that I simply don't know how to create an object as a byte so that it appears as a IEC 8859 character.  I've tried the Typed Arrays, but unable to achieve printing out each character and assigning it to the Telerik / Kendo control

> How do I use JS to create a string of ISO/IEC 8859-1  characters, and assign it to the control linked above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this function that takes a JavaScript number and determines if it's in the ISO/IEC 8859-1 codespace. Using this which `String.fromCharCode` allows you to construct the string you're looking for.

```
function inIsoIec8859_1(code) {
  if (typeof code !== "number" || code % 1 !== 0) {
    throw Error("code supplied is not a integer type.")
  }

  if (code > 255 || code < 32 || (code > 126 && code < 160)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true; 
}

var isoLatinCodespace = "";

var code = 0;
for (; code < 255; code += 1) {
  if (inIsoIec8859_1(code)) {
    var current = String.fromCharCode(code);
    isoLatinCodespace = isoLatinCodespace + current;
  }
}
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/IGoT/12

Because you accepted my original answer, it is above this line, unedited. I realized something after I posted that could be important.

If you plan on getting this value in a loop, this will serve your needs much better.

```
var MyApp = { 
  isoLatinString : (function() {
    var isoLatinCodespace = "";

    return function () {
      if (!isoLatinCodespace) {
        function inIsoIec8859_1(code) {
          if (typeof code !== "number" || code % 1 !== 0) {
            throw Error("code supplied is not a integer type.")
          }

          if (code > 255 || code < 32 || (code > 126 && code < 160)) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }

        var code = 0;
        for (; code < 255; code += 1) {
          if (inIsoIec8859_1(code)) {
            var current = String.fromCharCode(code);
            isoLatinCodespace = isoLatinCodespace + current;
          }
        }
      }
      return isoLatinCodespace; 
    }
  }())
}
```

Then later using `MyApp.isoLatinString()`. This new code only generates the string once, even if called multiple times. MyApp can be any object you're using to contain your application.

Comment: Hmm, that is a shame I can't encode non printable characters `< 32` or in the other banned range.  My goal is to transpose any arbitrary byte sequence into an ISO character.  E.g. I have 300 bytes that I want to be represented as 300 "strange" ISO characters, simply so I can maximise data utilisation

Comment: Well - this should be a pretty reasonable shell for what to do. You can feed `String.fromCharCode()` a value < x20 and it will do /something/. (It even generates a QR). It explodes on values [126, 160] though, which are part of the non-standard set in ISO Latin-1.

Comment: Here's with the < 32 range check removed: http://dojo.telerik.com/IrUT, and attempting to include the non-standard range (exploded) http://dojo.telerik.com/IrUT/2

Comment: I'm playing with that; thank you! I wonder if I'll break any readers encoding that value (if possible)